# Comparar el valor de 2 input y tomar el que tenga el valor mas grande

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando una función, pero todavía no la termino bien.

Consiste en tomar el valor del porcentaje y multiplicarlo por el valor de precio de lista, y poner el resultado en un campo llamado comisión.
El problema es que necesito hacer una comparación: cuando el precio de lista sea menor que el importe (PrecioLista<Importe), tomar el valor del precio de lista, si no, tomar el valor del importe y multiplicarlo por el porcentaje.
Hasta ahorita solo logro hacerlo con Precio de lista pero no sé como agregar el importe.

```
var input=document.querySelectorAll(".comision").value;
input.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
    e.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
});
var input2=document.querySelectorAll(".importe").value;
input2.forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click",multiplica);
    e.addEventListener("keyup",multiplica);
});

// funcion que genera la multiplicacion
function multiplica() {
    // nos posicionamos en el tr del producto
    var tr=this.closest("tr");

    var total=1;

    // recorremos todos los elementos del tr que tienen la clase .input
    var inputs=tr.querySelectorAll(".comision, .importe");
    inputs.forEach(function(e) {
        total*=e.value;
    });
}
```

Mi html

```
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="number" value="{{$ventas->PORCENTAJE}}" class="comision form-control" id="porcentaje" style="width:120px;height:40px">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="number"  class="comision form-control" id="preciolista" style="width:120px;height:40px">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="total form-control" id="comision" style="width:70px;height:40px">
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <input type="number" value="{{$ventas->IMPORTE}}" class="importe form-control" name="venta" id="venta" style="width:120px;height:40px">
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Esto es lo mismo que [preguntaste ayer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562988/seleccionar-entre-2-inputs-para-multiplicar-con-js)? Si es así, te sugiero mejorar tu pregunta original en vez de duplicar

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).Aunque has compartido el código, es mejor crear un ejemplo funcional para que se pueda resolver el problema en él.